# HTML5 MP3 player

Tags: html, mp3, html5-audio, ogg

I am trying to make a simple HTML5 player that has one button for play and pause, from 2 images, and that is it. Instead of having the standard 'controls'.

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src=".ogg" />
<source src=".mp3" />
</audio>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Simply add the CSS style setting the `width` as `45px`.

CSS:

```
audio { width: 45px; }
```

HTML:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This is how it looks in Google Chrome.

[image: Audio Button Showcase]

This is how it looks in IE 9.

[image]

Comment: Hi That is awesome, thanks! Is there a way that I can customize the play buttons or does that get very complicated?